# How to fetch a 3-level relationships where all foreign fields are lazy-loaded Lists without causing MultipleBagFetchException?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Category`, and it has a foreign key fields `allChildProducs`(a product have both a `category_id` and a `root_category_id`) that are all products whose top-level category is this `Category`, and `Product` entity has a field `productImages` that references all images belonging to this `Product`

Here are their relationships:

`Category` --1:N-- `Product` --1:N-- `ProductImage`

```
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    @NotNull
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "category_level")
    @NotNull
    private Integer categoryLevel;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    @NotNull
    private Long parentId;

    @Column(name = "category_icon")
    private String categoryIcon;

    @Column(name = "category_slogan")
    private String categorySlogan;

    @Column(name = "category_pic")
    private String categoryPic;

    @Column(name = "category_bg_color")
    private String categoryBgColor;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Category parentCategory;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Category> childCategories;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Product> products;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rootCategory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Product> allChildProducts;
}

public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    @NotNull
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "sold_num")
    @NotNull
    private int soldNum;

    @Column(name = "product_status")
    @NotNull
    private int productStatus;

    @Column(name = "content")
    @NotNull
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    @NotNull
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createTime;

    @Column(name = "update_time")
    @NotNull
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updateTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "root_category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Category rootCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<ProductImg> productImages;
}

public class ProductImage {
    @Id
    @Column(length = 64)
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @NotNull
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "url", length = 128)
    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "sort")
    @NotNull
    private int sort;

    @Column(name = "is_main")
    @NotNull
    private int isMain;

    @Column(name = "created_time")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @NotNull
    private Date createdTime;

    @Column(name = "updated_time")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @NotNull
    private Date updatedTime;
}
```

Now I am trying to fetch a list of `Category`, each element must have their `allChildProducts` loaded, and each `Product` in `allChildProducts` must also have their `productImages` loaded.

Here are all the failed attempts I have tried:

**1: Using multiple Join Fetch**

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.allChildProducts acp " +
        "LEFT JOIN FETCH acp.productImages " +
        "WHERE c.categoryLevel = :categoryLevel")
List<Category> findAllWithAllChildProductsAndImages(@Param("categoryLevel") int categoryLevel);
}
```

I got a `MultipleBagFetchException`

**2: Using Entity Graph**

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "category-with-products-and-images",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "allChildProducts", subgraph = "products-subgraph")
        },
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "products-subgraph",
                        attributeNodes = {
                                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "productImages")
                        }
                )
        }
)
public class Category { ... }

@EntityGraph(value = "category-with-products-and-images")
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c " +
       "WHERE c.categoryLevel = :categoryLevel"
)
List<Category> findAllWithAllChildProducts(@Param("categoryLevel") int categoryLevel);
```

I also got a `MultipleBagFetchException`

Here are all methods I have **NOT** tried that probably contains some serious flaws:

**1: Using FetchType.EAGER**

Made `allChildProducts` and `productImages` eager-loaded would solve the problem, but they would also cause some serious performance issues

**2: Changing lazy-loaded foreign key collection type from List to Set**

[This article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/) says it is also a bad idea as that would lead to Cartesian Product

**3: JOIN FETCH `allChildProducts` field of each Category entity, iterate through products and fetch the ProductImages field once by one**

Would cause too many I/O operations.

**4: Using @Transactional at the service-layer method that need to fetch the data**

This would made all lazy-loaded fields loaded, even the unused ones.

After all these attempts, I have come to the conclusion that I need to make a choice between having a Cartesian Product and Multiple I/O operations, so I have been thinking about just living with Cartesian Product and going with 2th or 4th unattempted methods. I am not sure if there is another way that would cause neither problems, so please give me some advice.

Comment: The cartesian product is the reason you get the multiple bag exception. 4, no it wouldn't load the lazy-loaded data, only will load the data that you are using. You might want to rethink your model, do you really need all those relationships? Aren't some of them easier with just a basic query (like all child products, does that really need to be mapped, or can it simply be queried when needed).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, but do you mean that when in a method with @Transactional annotation, lazy-loaded fields such as ```products``` and ```childCategories``` still would not be loaded when the entity is fetched until I explicitly access them like using ```c.getProducts```?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point of lazy loading.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. I always thought that using Transactional on a method would make all the lazy-loaded field of the entities fetched in that method loaded even when not used. Didn't realize I was wrong until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Hibernate you could use approach 3. with this improvement:

```
...
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<ProductImg> productImages;
```

As soon as you access the images from one of your products **all** the images for any product will be fetched within a single select.